# The useful application of Functor's Product and Coproduct

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

Could you show a simple code example which would display the useful application of `Data.Functor`'s `Product` and `Coproduct`?

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want an application of a functor over a product or a product of functors?

Comment: Product of functors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `Product` of a `Const` and a `Reader` can be used to easily implement  two-stage evaluation. For example, suppose you need to use some monadic effect between the two phases, but you want to make sure that your client code cannot do that (because you want to finely control how and when it happens):

```
type TwoPhase c r = Product (Const c) (Reader r)

run :: (Monad m, Monoid c) => (c -> m r) -> TwoPhase c r a -> m a
run prepare (Pair (Const deps, phase2)) = do
  r <- prepare deps
  return $ runReader phase2 r
```

Note that this of course only permits an `Applicative` interface for your API, not a monadic one; but that's what you usually want anyway in a situation like this.

Comment: This representation is what we ended up using (instead of the free applicative construction) to implement [these ideas](http://gergo.erdi.hu/blog/2012-12-01-static_analysis_with_applicatives/).

Answer (score 3):

A possible application of coproduct functor is used in [Data types a la carte](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=3D15F38DB60AA7B1623A86B780E3D982?doi=10.1.1.101.4131&rep=rep1&type=pdf). The idea is to use coproducts to combine *one level up* data type constructors.

Comment: The same applies to [Extensible effects](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/more.pdf).